# Есть ли мобильное приложение для сканирование штрих кода и его фото?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, мобильные-приложения, штрихкод

Всем привет!

Я фермер, у меня проблема с учетом животных. У меня их около 150 ( молодняк, коровы, быки)

Ветеринары РК мне выдали ушные бирки и систему учета. Ушная бирка содержит штрих код который при сканировании выдает ИД животного которая зарегистрирована в в учетной системе.

А это для меня отличная возможность для учета. У меня есть специальные узкие длинные вороты для прививки и т п работ. Вот тут я в месяц два раза буду делать пересчет. То есть буду каждый раз сканировать штрих код и записывать сразу же в гугл таблицы. А тут в гугл таблице напишу скрипт или просто через формулу сделаю сверку. 
Таким образом у меня будет решен вопрос учета. 
У нас семейная ферма, никто не знает точное количество животных так как ни кто не ведет журнал прибытия и убытия. Я пытался это сделать, но так и не смог. А с помощью полуавтоматического споба учета мне нужно будет обновить паспорт животного в учетная системе, добавить туда возраст, фото и т.п. описания. После этого два раза в месяц при пересчете если не будет кого то не хватать, я выявлю его.

Теперь мне нужно мобильное приложение для сканирования штрих кода и загрузки фото. Можете подсказать есть ли такие ? Любые вариации подойдут )

А по друдозатратам как это будет если написать приложение на андройд или IOS? [image: Пример ушной бирки]

Comment: Вопрос не связан с тематикой сайта.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: окей. Придумал решение

Comment: Ждем два дня и закрою вопрос

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, этот пункт не подходит, потому что _где_ найти никто не спрашивает)

Comment: @Qwertiy, весь вопрос укладывается в один-единственный абзац: «мне нужно мобильное приложение для сканирования штрих кода и загрузки фото. Можете подсказать есть ли такие?». если вы считаете, что для закрытия стоит использовать иную, нежели я привёл, формулировку — я ничего против не имею.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вообще-то я не понял про загрузку фото, т. к. после сканирования штрихкода должен бы получиться текст. Или там фото животного подразумевается?

Comment: Штрих код - выдает код товара. Плюс мне нужно добавить в базу фото товара.

Answer (score 1):

QuickScan сканирует и QR и штрих-коды

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ihandysoft.barcode&hl=en

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quick-scan-qr-code-reader/id483336864?mt=8

Но если нужно именно делать базу данных с подгрузкой фоток -- это не факт что найдешь готовое решение. Лично я не встречал.

---

upd: библиотека для считываний баркодов с изображений: http://www.barcodelib.com/csharp/barcode_reader_csharp.html

или код отсюда:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42852/Reading-Barcodes-from-an-Image-III

В принципе, должно быть относительно просто сделать нужное с даной либой.

Лично я бы, наверное, сделал бы простенькую апликуху под мобильный со встроенной SQLite бд со всеми нужными полями + возможностью сравнения записей по датах.

если занимался программированием раньше, это тебе должно датся достаточно просто. Если нет -- лучше, наверное, у кого-либо заказать.

Comment: Нее, этот не подойдет. С этого даже штрих код не возможно скопировать :(

Comment: Большое спасибо за идею. Раньше занимался программированием, но у меня сложно получалось

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем решил сделать так: черерез приложение отсканировать штрих код, фото и ид передавать по ватсапу. Это решение для регистрации. Таким образом добавим фото в паспорт.

В следующий через опросник гугла передаем просто отсканированный штрих код. 
Теперь необходимо воспроизвести ситуацию, отработать и попробовать.