# Как считать штрих-код?

Tags: php, штрихкод

Как получить значение с фотографии на которой изображен штрих-код с помощью php? Искал библиотеки, ни одна не опознает штрих-код из фотографии

Comment: Может это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/672958/17974 подойдёт?

Comment: По вашей ссылки к сожалению решение для C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

платное решение - https://www.ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start-guide/php-barcode-ocr-sdk/ (с примером использования, должен уметь работать и с фото)

бесплатное решение - https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zbarcode (но скорее всего не умеет работать с фото)

Answer (score 3):

Сканеры штрих-кода обычно работают в двух вариантах: 1) Эмуляция клавиатуры (те, кто подключаются через PS/2 или работают как USB HID) 2) Эмуляция COM-порта (те, которые подключаются к COM порту либо являются USB Serial Device)

Взаимодействие с первыми аналогично клавиатуре. Если во время работы устройства фокус на поле ввода, то ввод со сканера будет направлен в это поле.

Второй тип сканеров штрих-кода использует драйвер и записывает результат ввода в файл, куда именно - должно быть в описании устройства.

Если Вы хотите с минимальными затратами организовать «рабочее место оператора» с взаимодействием через веб, то вариант с USB HID — это ваш вариант. Вы просто с помощью PHP рисуете форму, с полем, куда JS-ом выставляете фокус. Оператор, «пикнув» сканером штрих кода, просто введет туда цифры. (И не забываем, какой еще ОГРОМНЫЙ плюс возникает, если штрих код потерт и не читается — оператор просто набивает артикул на клавиатуре в это поле.)

См. также https://toster.ru/q/10011 ; работа с СОМ-портом https://habrahabr.ru/post/240775/

Comment: Ваше решение я так понял подходит для работы с каким либо оборудованием, а тут нужно чтобы пользователь сфотографировал на телефон изображение со штрихкодом (возможно попадёт на изображение какиелибо лишнии элементы, текст и тд) и нужно из этого изображения выбрать только штрихкод и получить значение из него

Comment: По моему в вопросе ясно написано с фотографии, разве-что... поставить метку распознание образов.